# heaviside on matrix leads to crash

Tags: matlab

I do the following with a rather large sparse matrix:

```
imagesc(log10(abs(A(idx, idx))))
```

Works fine.

Then I do:

```
imagesc(heaviside(A(idx, idx)))
```

The console will hang and no longer respond then. **Is heaviside such an expensive function or do I missunderstand something?**

Comment: My blind guess would be that `heaviside` converts to a full array and you run out of memory. What are `idx` and your dimensions?

Comment: Show a [mcve], please. Heavyside is a symbolic maths function, do you really need that?

Comment: Note that the docs of `imagesc` don't say anything about sparse matrices, so you might crash anyway if you try to feed `A(idx,idx)` into `imagesc`.